# Can you help me about regexp?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, url

i'm having problem when i want to use regexp, i don't know to using 'or' , 'and'. like in if statement.

i'm having url like this

```
http://localhost:85/study/list
```

and i'm having the words(pattern to regexp) `/,/list/top`

when i try using this

```
url ="http://localhost:85/study/list"; 
regexp = RegExp(.*/?/list?/top);
var matches =  url.match(regexp); 
alert(matches);
```

and when i change url `to http://localhost:85/top` the word of /top not detection but /list is detection . what is wrong?

i wanna to match my words in that url , how i must create regexp for that?
please tell me your answer and please give me reference for the regexp
i'm newbie thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, you can test your expressions here [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/). It seems that the expression you using havo no effects.

This expression will match the last sub-directory of your url

```
(\w*)$
```

For example `http://localhost:85/study/list` will match `list`, `http://localhost:85/top` will match just `top`.

Try it! =)

Comment: yes, you true, but i want to math the last sub-directory with this words /,/list,top just that world...

Comment: So you want this `(list)|(top)` for just that couple of words?

Comment: (/list)|(/top) that is i want you true man, but just little again, i want to detect / in in the url in last character ex: 'http://localhost:85/list/' (/list)|(/top)|(/$) but the / is not detection . i'm sorry i'm very newbie..

Comment: Stop putting $ anywhere other than at the *very end*.  It's an end anchor.  Use ? to mean 'the character or stuff in parens is optional'.  So (list)? means list is optional.  Try this: `(list)?/(top)?/$`.

Comment: when i'm test in regex buddy 'http://localhost:85/another/' the last of / in url caracter not detection . that code same with my code...

Comment: But it is why I told you to use `(/\w*)$` but you said that you want the regex just to these two words (top and list). If you want for all of then you can't use `(list)|(top)` for example.

Comment: thanks for your answer i'm get the truth with this  `(/list)|(/top)|(/\W*)$` w is not small caracter must be capital caracter... example 'w' and 'W' that is any different between them..

Answer (score 1):

Put them in parenthesis, such as `(/list)?`.

Comment: i'm try like this (/list)?(/$)?(/top) but if the url changed to "http:/localhost:85/list" /list not detection?what wrong?

Comment: $ shouldn't be in there at all, and you're making it way too complicated, but the problem is likely that top doesn't have a ?, so it's expecting that now.

Answer (score 1):

list? matches lis or list. I think you want `(list)?`